# buttons gets repeated on every sorting of an item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I doing sorting of items and i want to show update button when sorting is done, when i have tried getting buttons repeated on number of time i am dragging and dropping the item.

here is my code what i have tried.

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
<div align="center" id="sortOrder"></div>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
            placeholder:"sortable-placeholder",
            update: function( event, ui ) {
                 console.log($("#sortable").sortable("toArray",{attribute:"pageid"}));
            },
            stop: function(event, ui){
                 showButton();
            }
        });
        $("button").click(function(){
             var order = $("#sortable").sortable("toArray",{attribute:"pageid"});
             $.post(
                 "/page.cfc",
                 {method:"Ordering",data:order}
             );
        });
    });
    function showButton(){
        var field = '#sortOrder';
        $node = '<button type="submit">Update</button>';
        $(field).after($node);
    };
</script>
```

can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code ? THanks

Comment: $(field).html($node);

Comment: @dandavis -now it shows single button but the data not being submitted when i submit ? :(

Answer (score 0):

`showButton` is constantly adding a new button element, so every time it gets called, it will add the button.

You might just want to use `$('button').show()` and `.hide()`

Comment: how can i have that with a condition will you please show me I am new to it ?